# regex to match either URL form

Tags: regex

I am matching for the username portion in Twitter profile URLs - eg. http://www.twitter.com/joebloggs

Currently, I'm successfully using http://www.twitter.com/(\w+)

But, in some instances, the source URLs are in the format http://www.twitter.com/@joebloggs

This is unnecessary, but I still need to find "joebloggs" all the same. So I need to be matching for either the format without @ or with @.

I have tried various methods using the pipe or vertical bar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `@` optional by using:

```
^http:\/\/www\.twitter\.com\/@?(\w+)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^            # match start of input
http:        # match literal http://
\/\/         # match 2 // (escaping is needed for some regex engines)
www          # match literal www
\.           # match literal dot (escaping since dot is special meta char)
twitter\.com # match literal twitter.com
\/           # match literal /
@?           # match optional @
(\w+)        # match 1 or more word characters and group it
```

Comment: If you take the @ out of the capture, then he will always get "joebloggs" (regardless of the presence of the @): `^http:\/\/www\.twitter\.com\/@?(\w+)`

Comment: I wasn't sure if `@` needs be to be in captured text or not. But yes I agree if intent is always capture `joebloggs` then regex must be: `^http:\/\/www\.twitter\.com\/@(?\w+)`

Comment: With the first answer, matches ended up including the @. I need it _stripped_ where it is in the URL. The second replies work. Thank-you. How can I understand what is going on in the regex here... ? 1) ^ is to match where http://www.twitter.com/ is the beginning of a string? 2) You have to escape the period? 3) I don't fully understand the logic behind @(?\w+)

Comment: I have added some explanation in answer.

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.